# TFTransform ValueError: "Split does not exist over all example artifacts"

Tags: tfx

I'm attempting to construct a TFX pipeline, but keep running into an error during the TFTransform component stem. After diving into the error message and its code on GitHub, it appears to have something to do with a function `def get_split_uris()`. From what I can glean, there is a mismatch between the number of Artifacts being consumed by this function during runtime and the number of URIs being retrieved and being matched back to this list.

It's odd because my `CSVExampleGen()` function doesn't seem to have any problems ingesting my original data set that's already split into two CSV files: 'target' and 'candidate'. I cannot find any documentation on this error on the TFX website so my apologies for not having more information.

I can provide additional details if needed.

Comment: In order to expedite the trouble-shooting process, please provide a code snippet to reproduce the issue reported here. Thanks!